# Follow the symlink and get the absolute path with QFileInfo

Tags: c++, qt

I'm coding with C++ and Qt.

I want to follow the symlink and get the absolute path with `QFileInfo`.

For example, `/usr/local/extra` is an symlink for `/home/extra`.
Then I need to convert `/usr/local/extra/my_directory/` to `/home/extra/my_directory`.

I tried `QFileInfo(path).canonicalPath()` but it returns the parent directory only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use QFileInfo::canonicalFilePath() instead. canonicalPath() always returns the parent directory, while canonicalFilePath() actually includes the file (or directory) itself.

Answer (score 1):

How about `QFileInfo::symLinkTarget()` ?

> QString QFileInfo::symLinkTarget() const Returns the absolute path to
>   the file or directory a symlink (or shortcut on Windows) points to, or
>   a an empty string if the object isn't a symbolic link. This name may
>   not represent an existing file; it is only a string.
>   QFileInfo::exists() returns true if the symlink points to an existing
>   file. This function was introduced in Qt 4.2. See also exists(),
>   isSymLink(), isDir(), and isFile().

Answer (score 0):

After I asked the question, I think I found the solution.
I should use `QDir(path).canonicalPath()` instead of `QFileInfo(path).canonicalPath()`.

> QString QDir::canonicalPath () const Returns the canonical path, i.e.
>   a path without symbolic links or redundant "." or ".." elements. On
>   systems that do not have symbolic links this function will always
>   return the same string that absolutePath() returns. If the canonical
>   path does not exist (normally due to dangling symbolic links)
>   canonicalPath() returns an empty string. Example:

```
 // where /local/bin is a symlink to /usr/bin
 QString bin = "/local/bin";
 QDir binDir(bin);
 QString canonicalBin = binDir.canonicalPath();
 // canonicalBin now equals "/usr/bin"

 QString ls = "/local/bin/ls";       // where ls is the executable "ls"
 QDir lsDir(ls);
 QString canonicalLs = lsDir.canonicalPath();
 // canonicalLS now equals "/usr/bin/ls".
```